# php only adding the first digit instead of entire number

Tags: php, addition

I recently moved my website over to Blue Host and this function that's part of a loop:

```
if ($InvoiceType == '18')
{
    echo 'Sum Before addition = ' . $sumInvoice . '<br/>';
    $sumInvoice += $complete[$key][5];
    print 'Invoice being added = ' . $complete[$key][5] . '<br/>' 
        . 'Sum after addition = '. $sumInvoice . '<br/>';
}
```

Is returning this:

```
Sum Before addition = 0
Invoice being added = 15174.20
Sum after addition = 1
Sum Before addition = 1
Invoice being added = 4604.25
Sum after addition = 5
Sum Before addition = 5
Invoice being added = 63810.83
Sum after addition = 11
```

**dump of $complete:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2161
        [1] => 638697
        [2] => CLIV0286
        [3] => Central Medical Supply Inc.
        [4] => 0.00
        [5] => 15174.20
        [6] => 04/01/2011
        [7] => 2/1-2/28/11 Fairlawn
        [8] => PM2
        [9] => 18
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2161
        [1] => 638698
        [2] => CLIV0286
        [3] => Central Medical Supply Inc.
        [4] => 0.00
        [5] => 4604.25
        [6] => 04/01/2011
        [7] => 2/1-2/28/11 Atrium
        [8] => PM2
        [9] => 18
    )
    [2] => Array
        (
        [0] => 2161
        [1] => 638699
        [2] => CLIV0286
        [3] => Central Medical Supply Inc.
        [4] => 0.00
        [5] => 63810.83
        [6] => 04/01/2011
        [7] => 2/1-2/28/11 Parsippany
        [8] => PM2
        [9] => 18
    )
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of $complete. You can do this by going print_r($complete)

Comment: += works fine; I think you need to show us $complete

Comment: Its being printed in the example above.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2161 [1] => 638697 [2] => CLIV0286 [3] => Central Medical Supply Inc. [4] => 0.00 [5] => 15174.20 [6] => 04/01/2011 [7] => 2/1-2/28/11 Fairlawn [8] => PM2 [9] => 18 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2161 [1] => 638698 [2] => CLIV0286 [3] => Central Medical Supply Inc. [4] => 0.00 [5] => 4604.25 [6] => 04/01/2011 [7] => 2/1-2/28/11 Atrium [8] => PM2 [9] => 18 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 2161 [1] => 638699 [2] => CLIV0286 [3] => Central Medical Supply Inc. [4] => 0.00 [5] => 63810.83 [6] => 04/01/2011 [7] => 2/1-2/28/11 Parsippany [8] => PM2 [9] => 18 )

Comment: What PHP version is this running on?

Comment: What is $Key? is it an integer?

Answer (score 1):

So this does not work?

```
$sumInvoice = 0;
//Init Loop
if ($InvoiceType == '18')
{
    echo 'Sum Before addition = ' . $sumInvoice . '<br/>';
    $sumInvoice = 0 + floatval(trim($complete[$key][5])) + floatval($sumInvoice);
    print 'Invoice being added = ' . $complete[$key][5] . '<br/>' 
        . 'Sum after addition = '. $sumInvoice . '<br/>';
}
```

Try this small scale test:

```
$val = "10.25";
echo (floatval($val) + 10);
```

Comment: So $sumInvoice is definately defined as an int before it is used?

Comment: Its only being defined like this: $sumInvoice = 0;  Also it is a float.

Comment: Perhaps try doing a small scale test like the one I added above.

Comment: Try var_dump($complete[$key]);

Comment: I have updated the main code above by adding a trim() around `$complete[$key][5]`. Try that.

Comment: Just tried it now and still am experiencing the same issue.  I just tested this on the old server where I last saw it work properly, but I see the same thing happening there now.  I think its an issue with the data, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: So I try to do echo $amount = is_float($complete[$key][5]) or is_int, it doesn't return anything at all.  This leads me to believe that the query that I'm running on the db and then exporting to a csv is returning an odd data type which is then producing this.  Any ideas on how I can research this further?

Comment: you could try combining the value with a string and then converting it to a float? `+= floatval(trim("".$complete[$key][5]));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sumInvoice += (float)$complete[$key][5];
```

or

```
$sumInvoice += floatval( $complete[$key][5] );
```

[floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)